# Convert integer within a list into a string to be written to a text file and later retrieved

Tags: python, text, type-conversion, python-3.4

I am trying to make a `stats.txt` file where I can store `wins`, `draws`, and `losses`. Thus far, the only way I have been able to retrieve the values AND modify them when the program runs is by opening them with `.readlines()` and then assigning them to a variable as an integer within a list (see below).

My issue is that I can't seem to find a way to write them back to a text file as they are in list form. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

The text file is in this format:

```
0\n
0\n
0\n
```

Nothing else is written in it other that the three 0's, followed by `enter.`

My code is as follows:

```
stats = open("C:/Users/JawshBawx/Documents/LiClipse Workspace/RPScLSp/RPScLSp_Src/Stats.txt","r")
lines = stats.readlines()
wins = list(int(val) for val in lines[0].split())
draws = list(int(val) for val in lines[1].split())
losses = list(int(val) for val in lines[2].split())
```

If I assign these without `list,` output becomes: `generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000011CEF216CA8` when printed, and I can't modify the values with +1.

```
if result == 0:
    print("Draw!")
    draws = [x + 1 for x in draws]

elif result == 1:
    print(ai_var+" Wins!")
    losses = [x + 1 for x in losses]

elif result == 2:
    print(ai_var+" Wins!")
    losses = [x + 1 for x in losses]

elif result == 3:
    print(user_var+" Wins!")
    wins = [x + 1 for x in wins]

else:
    print(user_var+" Wins!")
    wins = [x + 1 for x in wins]

print(wins)
print(draws)
print(losses)

stats.close
with open("C:/Users/JawshBawx/Documents/LiClipse Workspace/RPScLSp/RPScLSp_Src/Stats.txt","w") as f:
    f.write(wins)
    f.write(draws)
    f.write(losses)
```

My result is:

```
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not list
```

I cannot get this to convert to string, and write in in such a way that it will be retrieved in the same format as I need it to be as to be able to process i every time the program runs.

I'd rather just import the values in the text file as integers, modify them, then write them as integers, but I haven't found a way to do that yet. I know there must be better ways to do the above.

Comment: Note: `[int(val) for val in lines[0].split()]` doesn't require `list`.

Comment: `stats.close` doesn't close the file, you need to _call_ it `stats.close()`

Comment: Or use the `with` statement for reading as well. You're only doing `readlines()` on the file, after that you don't need the file and can close it.

Comment: You have to convert the list to a string, as per the suggested TypeError. You could do e.g. `f.write(str(wins))`, but the saved output may not be what you want. Or something like `f.write(','.join([str(win) for win in wins]))`. By then, you may start to think about the csv module, or even numpy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should use [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) instead of [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) in this case. [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) split the string by *empty letters* (spaces, newlines, tabs, etc.) and return a list.

   However, it looks like that you don't need a list here and just want remove that `\n`, then, you can use [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip). Which removes the *empty letters* after and before the string.

   Demo:

   ```
   >>> s = '0\n'
   >>> s
   '0\n'
   >>> s.strip()
   '0'
   >>> s.split()
   ['0']   
   >>> int(s.strip())
   0
   ```
2. Then, it's an int object. So you can just totally drop these *list comprehension* and use `object += 1`.

   However, you can just use `str()` function to convert it to a string object when you write it back to a file.

   Remember also add a `+\n` if you don't want them all in one line:

   ```
   with open("C:/Users/JawshBawx/Documents/LiClipse Workspace/RPScLSp/RPScLSp_Src/Stats.txt", "r") as f:
       lines = f.readlines()
       wins = int(lines[0].strip())
       draws = int(lines[1].strip())
       losses = int(lines[2].strip())

   if result == 0:
       print("Draw!")
       draws += 1

   elif result in [1, 2]:
       print(ai_var+" Wins!")
       losses += 1

   else:
       print(user_var+" Wins!")
       wins += 1

   with open("C:/Users/JawshBawx/Documents/LiClipse Workspace/RPScLSp/RPScLSp_Src/Stats.txt","w") as f:
       f.write(str(wins)+'\n')
       f.write(str(draws)+'\n')
       f.write(str(losses)+'\n')
   ```

Comment: This looks almost perfect! when I run this though, I'm getting this error at: wins += 1
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

Comment: @Jawshbawx: Well, I've edited my answer. Take a look at it.

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you very much, that was getting frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `writelines()` instead of `write()` to write an iterable object (such as a list of strings), similar to how the method for obtaining a single string is `read()` and the method to get a list of strings is `readlines()`.